# Custom checkbox in silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, custom-controls

How to create custom checkbox that looks like the one shown below. The checkboxes are dynamically drawn and can have custom colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can just style it. Take the style from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278078%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and change it. The key component in the style is [VisualStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), make sure you understand what it does.

Also you can create a custom control, you can read about it, for example, [here](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Creating-a-Skinnable-Custom-Control-in-Silverlight-3-Part-I.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is, create a custom control called ImageCheckBox which inherits from the default CheckBox class, add in three dependency properties of type `ImageSource`, called CheckedImage, IndeterminateImage and UncheckedImage. Just toggle their `Visibility` or `Opacity` based on the control's `CheckStates`, i.e. Checked, Unchecked and Indeterminate.